# How do I return Last() as an IEnumerable from a DataTable

Tags: c#

How do I return Last() as an IEnumerable from a DataTable?

I want IEnumerable because I may pass in a larger subset of rows.

```
public static void Set(IEnumerable<DataRow> rowsToProcess)
{
    //Do something with rowsToProcess;
}

DataTable data;

//This works:
Set(Data.AsEnumerable());

//This gives an error:
Set(Data.AsEnumerable().Last());
```

> Cannot convert from `DataRow` to `IEnumerable<DataRow>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could put it in an array:

```
Set(new[]{ Data.AsEnumerable().Last() });
```

or you could use this:

```
Set(Data.AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(1));
```

or this:

```
Set(Data.AsEnumerable().Skip(Data.Rows.Count - 1));
```

this non-LINQ approach is probably the most efficient way, because it avoids a loop:

```
Set(new[]{ Data.Rows[Data.Rows.Count-1] });
```

---

For what it's worth, you could also use following extension ;-)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsSequence<T>(this T obj)
{
    yield return obj;
}
```

...

```
Set(Data.AsEnumerable().Last().AsSequence());
```

Comment: Would those answers not pull all records into memory, especially `Set(new[]{ Data.AsEnumerable().Last() });` ?

Comment: @JamieTaylor: No, that will create an array with a single DataRow

Comment: Does Set(new[]{ Data.Rows[Data.Rows.Count-1] }); give an IEnumerator. i.e. Can I affect values in Data from within Set?

Comment: @ManInMoon: it's not deferred executed, it's an array with a single item. But if you modify the DataRow you will modify the DataTable because a `DataRow` is a reference type. It's not quite clear what you mean though. You can also acceess the `DataTable` itself from `Set` via [`row.Table`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.table(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `.AsEnumerable().Last()` will indeed consume all the rows and then return only the last one. If you try just `.Last()` it might work better.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: that doesn't work because `DataTable` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. `DataTable.Rows` also just implements `IEnumerable`, that's why you have to use `AsEnumerable` first to cast the objects to `DataRow` and to be able to use LINQ. If performance matters i'd use my last approach: `new[]{ Data.Rows[Data.Rows.Count-1] }`